# How to combine lists of objects in list to new list in Dart?

Tags: list, dart

The question uses the word "List" quite often and maybe confusing without further explanation, so let me give you a quick example to illustrate what I mean:

Let's say I got a class called `City`. It contains a `List<House> houses`. And every `House` contains a `List<Person> persons` with contains all the Persons living in the building.

So to get the list of people living in house `5` I would have to use `city.houses[5].people`. In this scenario what would be the most efficient way to get a list of all the people living in the city itself?

Should I create a separate list in the `City` class and add all people in there?
Should I implement a `getPeople` method in the `City` class that uses a for-loop that adds the people from each building to a new list and returns it every time? Or is there a more efficient way to achieve this in Dart.

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for the most efficient way, *and* for how to design API for it.
Those two are separate questions.

The most efficient way to *collect* the people living in the houses is one of:

```dart
 city.houses.expand((h) => h.people);
 // or
 [for (var h in city.houses) ...h.people]
```

*If a person can live in more than one house, you might want to make it a set instead of a list.*

From an API design point-of-view, the property of "all the people in all the houses" can belong as a getter on the `city`. In that case, I'd probably make it `city.population`, so declared as `List<People> get population => ...;`.

You can choose to compute the list every time it's asked for, cache the list when it's first asked for, or create it when the city object is created—assuming it's an immutable city.
If the city object or, worse, the individual houses can be modified, then you'll need to invalidate the cache when anything changes. That's fairly complicated and easy to get wrong, and I'd probably go for computing the result each time it's asked for. Only cache or precompute the list if you have an efficient way to detect mutations and you actually expect the population to be queried multiple times between mutations.

Another factor is how often the getter is going to be used. If it's very often, then caching or precomputing is definitely the way to go. If very rare, then computing it each time is not going to be a big overhead. If it's exceedingly rare, then the property might not be worth putting on the `city` at all, and you could just provide a separate static helper function `populationOf(City city) => ...`. Or just not, since the expressions above are not that hard to write for someone who happens to need the entire population.

So, if caching:

```dart
class City { 
  ...
  List<People>? _population;
  ...
  List<People> get population => 
      _population ??= [for (var h in houses) ...h.people];
}
```

If precomputing:

```dart
class City {
  final List<People> population;
  ...
  City(this.houses, ...) : population = [for (var h in houses) ...h.people];
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context and use-case of the situation. If getting all people for each city is the main or most frequently called task for your program, I would separate the people as a list which will reduce the number of operations when doing that task. You could also create a `getPeople` method if you need to perform extra effects when getting the list. Or if you wish to have a very OOPy code base, you could separate each primary key as a class to get full advantage of inheritance. For example, `City`, `House`, and `Person` classes.

There are multiple ways you can configure your data structure. But I bet they don't really matter in a simple program. If you wish to use the most efficient way in a large program, you could choose a structure that does the best in terms of the heaviest task.

Comment: "separate each primary key as a class"
Can you please explain what you mean with this?

Comment: I meant to have each `City`, `House`, and `Person` as separate classes.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't write it clearly enough in my original post:
City, House, and Person are separate classes. City contains a List<House> houses and each item in this list contains a List<Person> persons and I want to get a list of all the persons in the entire City.

Comment: Yes, it is :). But do you know of a efficient way to integrate all the Lists of the type Person in the separate Houses into a single list of all the Persons in the entire City?

Comment: yes, I've answered my take "choose a structure that does the best in terms of the heaviest task"

Comment: OK, so I should just choose either the getPeope function with a loop or create a separate list of people directly in my City class depending on my use-case, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225602/discussion-between-frenco-and-stefan).